# For Each loop won't delete all rows with specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all rows that do not contain the value "Total" in Range("B11:B25").

Below is my code.

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("B11:B25")
    If cell.Value <> "Total" Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Above code will only delete some rows with cells that do not have the value "Total". If I have to delete all rows that do not contain "Total", I will have to run this multiple times which is not practical.

Comment: When you delete rows you should always loop from bottom to top.

Comment: and I wouldn't name a variable `cell` which is probably a reserved word

Comment: @PatrickHonorez `cell` is not a reserved word in vba. I can't find any source for this from Microsoft, but [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/syntax/keywords.htm) is what I found with a quick google search

Comment: @PatrickHonorez that is an extremely naive and inefficient idea. Modifying the collection you're iterating is terrible advice in any language, VBA isn't any different. Also if `cell` was illegal, the code wouldn't compile. VBA isn't only hosted in Excel; not all VBA host applications have cells. `cell` being "reserved" makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying a collection you're iterating is always a bad idea. Sure you could start at the bottom and call it a day, but then your next question is going to be "my code is painfully slow, how do I make it faster?"

Have a `CombineRanges` function responsible for `Union`-ing ranges:

```
Private Function CombineRanges(ByVal source As Range, ByVal toCombine As Range) As Range
    If source Is Nothing Then
        Set CombineRanges = toCombine
    Else
        Set CombineRanges = Union(source, toCombine)
    End If
End Function
```

Now, change your loop so that instead of deleting rows, it determines what rows need to be removed:

```
Dim toDelete As Range
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B11:B25")
    If cell.Value <> "Total" Then Set toDelete = CombineRanges(toDelete, cell)
Next

If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.EntireRow.Delete
```

And now you have an efficient loop (always iterate object collections with a `For Each` loop) that doesn't modify the object collection it's iterating, does only one thing, and you have a single `Delete` operation going on, which will only trigger a single worksheet `Changed` event, one single recalculation, and will perform well regardless of whether you're deleting 20 or 2000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will loop from row 25 to 11 backwards and find anything not "Total"

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 25 To 11 Step -1 ' change to whatever row you want
    If Range("B" & i) <> "Total" Then
        Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks this work. However how do I reverse loop if I don't know where my data ends in that column. Data always starts in B11. I tried using VBA's .end function but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If your data always starts in B11 and is continuous to the end (no empty rows) then use `For i = 11 to Cells(11,2).End(xlDown).Row Step -1` As a side note, this, and the rest of the code, assumes `ActiveSheet` which could be a bad idea if you have multiple sheets or workbooks which could be the active one.