# Iterating through a column and deleting multiple rows based on the values in the column

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

I need to remove lines from an Excel file where the value nets to zero with another line. 1,000 lines out of 10,000 may end up being deleted.

I sort the lines by absolute value from largest to smallest (for now done manually, I can add this later), then iterating through the values and deleting the lines that net to zero.

I have written code to execute on 50 lines, however it doesn't work:

```
Sub delete_row()

    Dim activerow As Integer
    
    activerow = 2

    Do
            
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(activerow, 13).Select + ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = 0 Then
            
            Rows("activerow:activerow + 1").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                       
        Else: activerow = activerow + 1
            
        End If
            
    Loop Until activerow = 50

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a beginning (explanations in comments):

```
Sub delete_row()
    Dim iRow As Long ' in Excel sheet you can handle up to 1 million row
                     ' Integer type reaches up to some 32 thousands
                     ' Long type allows for far more

    For iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 ' step backwards from column M (column index 13) last not empty cell row index to 2
        If Cells(iRow, 13).Value + Cells(iRow + 1, 13) = 0 Then Cells(iRow, 13).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next
End Sub
```

when deleting rows you Always have to start from the last one and then loop bakwards, to avoid missing any line

you hardy really need to `Select` anything (look at [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
)

Comment: Note that the solution provided starts at the bottom and works up. that is an important part when deleting rows.

Comment: @SmileyFtW, added the note in answer

Comment: This is a great start and will likely work perfectly for OP; for a technically better solution see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975239/for-loop-not-fully-cycling-in-excel-vba/59975507#59975507).

Comment: @HaydenMoss, `Union()` based methods have their drawbacks as well, when it comes to handling a large amount of rows. But should ever there be universal "technically better solution", then it would use a mix of Filters and Sorting

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! @HaydenMoss I'm not quite ready for this just yet haha

Comment: @Josh, you are welcome. And … you're never ready if you never try…