# How can I make Union cooperate with Listrows?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to incorporate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975239/for-loop-not-fully-cycling-in-excel-vba/59975507#59975507) post into my project to delete many rows at once based on if they contain a certain value.  However, once I get to Union, it hits me with Error 5.  I'm guessing it's just the syntax since I'm not very used to working with ranges.

```
Public Sub IPOSheetProxy_Delete(ByVal value As String)
    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    Dim toDelete As Range
    For Each currentRow In Table.ListRows
    'table is declared elsewhere, but it's sheet1.listobjects(1)
        If currentRow.Range(columnindex:=1) = value Then
            Set toDelete = CombineRanges(currentRow.Range(), toDelete)
            'also tried this
            'For Each currentCol In Table.ListColumns
                'Set toDelete = CombineRanges(currentRow.Range(columnindex:=currentCol.Index), toDelete)
            'Next

        End If
    Next
    If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

here's the code for CombineRanges:

```
Private Function CombineRanges(ByVal source As Range, ByVal toCombine As Range) As Range
'credit Mathieu Guindon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975239/for-loop-not-fully-cycling-in-excel-vba/59975507#59975507
    If source Is Nothing Then
        'note: returns Nothing if toCombine is Nothing
        Set CombineRanges = toCombine
    Else
        'here's where it breaks, Err 5: invalid procedure call or argument
        Set CombineRanges = Union(source, toCombine)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Try replacing `currentRow.Range()` with `currentRow.Range`.

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, no dice :(

Comment: `Set toDelete = CombineRanges(toDelete, currentRow.Range)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, drop the parentheses after `currentRow.Range`.

Then, you need to flip the arguments around in the call to `CombineRanges`:

```
Set toDelete = CombineRanges(toDelete, currentRow.Range)
```

The clue as to the order is the following lines:

```
If source Is Nothing Then
    'note: returns Nothing if toCombine is Nothing
    Set CombineRanges = toCombine
```

If the `source` (namely the *first* parameter) `Is Nothing`, then return only `toCombine`. You had it backwards.